# How can we find the appropriate values of unknowns such that the following expression must be a real number? `FindInstance`

Tags: findinstance

**Question:** I have some mathematical functions including various parameters. I want to find instances for the parameters such that the function must be in a real domain after substituting the values of parameters into the mathematical functions.

**For example;**

```
expr = 3^(1/4)*Sqrt[(I*a*b*Sqrt[d]*Sqrt[v]*Sech[(1/2)*Sqrt[a]*((-t)*v + x)]^2)/(Sqrt[a*c*\[Alpha] - 8*c*\[Kappa] + 4*c*\[Alpha]*\[Kappa]^2]*(b^2 - a*d*(1 + Tanh[(1/2)*Sqrt[a]*((-t)*v + x)])^2))]
```

How can we find the appropriate positive integer values of unknowns `v, \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Kappa], \[CapitalPhi]` such that the following expression must be a real number? (where the independent variables `x` and `t` are real numbers.)

**An example for Manual selection of the parameters:**

If we select

`parameters={v -> 1, \[Alpha] -> 1, \[Beta] -> 2, \[Kappa] -> 1, \[CapitalPhi] ->  2, c -> 1, a -> 2, b -> 3, d -> 1}`,

and `expr /. parameters`, we get

`2^(1/4)*3^(3/4)*Sqrt[Sech[(-t + x)/Sqrt[2]]^2/(9 - 2*(1 + Tanh[(-t + x)/Sqrt[2]])^2)]`

**How can we achieve this in `Mathematica 13.2`?**

In my opinion,

**Step.1:** firstly we will find the terms including square roots in `expr`.

**Step.2:** And we will create conditions such that the inside of the roots should be equal or greater than zero.

**Step.3:** And lastly, we will use `FindInstance` such that the conditions hold.

Answer (score 2):

Try `FunctionDomain`:

```
FunctionDomain[ {
Sqrt[-((I*Sqrt[v]*Sech[((-t)*v + x)*Sqrt[a]]*a*Sqrt[c])/(Sqrt[-8*\[Kappa]*c +4*\[Alpha]*\[Kappa]^2*c + \[Alpha]*c*a]*((-Sech[((-t)*v + x)*Sqrt[a]])*b + Sqrt[c^2 - 4*a*b])))], 
Element[{a, b, c, v, \[Alpha], \[Kappa]}, Integers]},
{a, b, c,v, \[Alpha], \[Kappa]}, Reals ]
(*False*)
```

Unfortunately result is `False`, Mathematica cannot find an instance!

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the post.